# In Bash, how to read a file and take each line as incremental variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a file like below: (list.txt)

```
127.0.0.1 us
127.0.0.2 uk
127.0.0.3 cn
127.0.0.4 fr
127.0.0.5 ru
127.0.0.6 bd
127.0.0.7 hk
```

I wanted to make an script which will show the user as items to chose.

```
bash ping.sh
Which ip you want to test?

1) 127.0.0.1-us
2) 127.0.0.2-uk
3) 127.0.0.3-cn
4) 127.0.0.4-fr
5) 127.0.0.5-ru
6) 127.0.0.6-bd
7) 127.0.0.7-hk

Input: 6

ping -c 5 127.0.0.6
```

That list will change whenever the file changes. How can i do that ?

Comment: Hi Fahad, just curious, but is none (any )of the answers acceptable to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Input: "

while read -r addr tld; do
  addrlist+=( "$addr" ) 
done < list.txt

echo "Which ip you want to test?"

select addr in "${addrlist[@]}"; do
  ping -c5 "$addr"
  break;
done
```

---

Note that if your file had contained just a single (address) field, you could have use the bash `mapfile` built-in (or its synonym `readarray`)

```
mapfile -t addrlist < list.txt
```

to fill the array without explicit looping. If you want the exact hyphenated list shown in the original question then you could do something like

```
mapfile -t addrlist < list.txt

echo "Which ip you want to test?"

select addr in "${addrlist[@]// /-}"; do
  ping -c5 "${addr%%-*}"
  break;
done
```

but the code starts to get ugly IMHO.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, its complete and its a shell script. one question why you use `-r` on the read statement and also what does the `tld` do in the `read` statement?

Comment: I think I see why the `tld` - you are stripping the suffixes, e.g. `-us`  because `read` is assigning the suffix to `tld` which you dont use. and I guess `tld` is *too long didnt read* ? hah

Comment: `-r` isn't strictly necessary in this case, but it prevents `read` from interpreting any backslash escape sequences in the input. Yes `tld` is just a placeholder variable (since the input file has two fields).

Comment: oh so you mean if `list.txt` had an entry like `127.0.0.1 us\¬` (where `¬` is a newline character) normally read would say *"oh the ¬ is escaped - so assume this line AND the next are all part of the same line"* but the `-r` is telling read if you encounter `\¬` treat it as a line break. or is it saying just ignore `\¬` sequences altogether?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
select choice in $(cat list.txt; echo exit)
do
    # echo "$REPLY : $choice"
    if [[ $choice != "exit" ]]
    then
        echo "your choice was: "$choice
        # Run your program here
    else
        exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: @kos good spotting. I put the exit in front of the `cat` thinking that it wouldn't matter if the number of lines of `list.txt` changed. But yeah putting it after is better, its just going to get appended  to the cat output

Comment: Nah, sorry about that, actually it was a pretty empty complaint. I just misread the code and thought it wouldn't have worked that way (wrong, it indeed works).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by `bash`you meant `cli` (terminal) command to do the job. Only the *communicational* section is done by `python` the command itself is (of course) done by `ping`

All in one, in a small `python` script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

print("Which ip do you want to test?\n")
# create a numbered list of the lines
ips = list(enumerate(open(sys.argv[1]).read().splitlines()))
[print(str(i+1)+") "+ip) for i, ip in ips]
# run the command to ping
subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "5", ips[int(input("\ninput: "))-1][1]])
```

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `ping_ip.py`
- Run it with your `list.txt` as argument:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/ping_ip.py /path/to/list.txt`
  ```

  [image]

#### Note

The argument "5" (number of pings) is in the line:

```
subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "5", ips[int(input("\ninput: "))-1][1]])
```

but can very well be changed to be used as an argument *while running the script*. If that would be handy, please mention.

Comment: I was looking for shell script. But this one seems to be working ... i will check ifi can perfectly implement ... Thank You.

Comment: @FahadAhammed if you need any change, different kind of output or anything, all can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've concocted in about 5 - 10 minutes of just playing with AWK.

```
$ select entry in $(awk '{printf "%s-%s ",$1,$2}'  ips.txt) ; do                                      
> ip_address=$(awk -F '-' '{print $1}' <<< "$entry" )                                                                 
> echo "You selected "  "$ip_address"
> done
1) 127.0.0.1-us
2) 127.0.0.2-uk
3) 127.0.0.3-cn
4) 127.0.0.4-fr
5) 127.0.0.5-ru
6) 127.0.0.6-bd
7) 127.0.0.7-hk
#? 2
You selected  127.0.0.2
```

The tricky part in your question is just processing  the lines of text file that can be used appropriately by the `select` structure, because you have two entries per line there. Well , why not make them into one item  and just post process to extract the ip address ? That's exactly what I'm doing in the code above.

Note that the first parameter substitution is left unquoted on purpose - we do want the first command to expand to each separate item separated by spaces, we don't want it to be treated as one string.

What's good about this approach is that it's immune to missing location, for example if in choice #2 `uk` was missing, we would still be able to read 127.0.0.2